# Installation of visual studio on win 10 64

Tags: vb.net, installation

I am trying to get any visual studio 201x running on windows 10 .
My system is as follows. 
Amd 955 
Am3+ sabertooth mb
16 gb 1600 ram
250 gb hdd avl

Express 13 update 5 for desktop.
 from web gets as far as install cannot continue because some components failed 
 Critical error fatsl error during installation 
Warning windows sdk for windows store apps direct x x86 remote user cancelled instalation. (i didnt touch it)

Log error shows 0x80070642 six times in a row for ux aborted on dl progress 
Ux aborted on cache progress 
And then a few failed messages no interuption of my isp occurred please help.

Comment: Can you install Windows SDK separately? Does it come up with the same error?